# Best pattern for injecting handler implementation?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Let's say I have a third party C++ library I'd like to use. It's full of subclasses of a Component base class. The Component base has virtual handlers for myriad events, such as onEvent().

I'd like to provide an implementation for this, which is an interface to define the handlers as std::function<> lambdas (so I can define implementations dynamically). Of course, the resulting mixed-in subclass should still be usable as its base class.

My naive solution is to create a mixin adapter template which provides that dynamic implementation. Here's a sample of what I'm talking about. Is there a better way, or a more standard idiom I can follow?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

// Third-party SDK

// Base class

class Component
{
public:
    virtual void onEvent(int val)
    {
    }
};

// Component subclass

class FooComponent : public Component
{
};

// My overlay interface to set an event handler

class IAdapter
{
public:
    virtual void setOnEventHandler(const std::function<void(int)>& handler) = 0;
};

// Mixin implementor -- only one is given, but there could be one for each type of handler

template <typename Base>
class AdapterImpl1 : public IAdapter, public Base
{
public:
    virtual void setOnEventHandler(const std::function<void(int)>& handler) override
    {
        m_onEventHandler = handler;
    }

    virtual void onEvent(int val) override
    {
        if (m_onEventHandler)
        {
            m_onEventHandler(val);
        }
    }

private:
    std::function<void(int)> m_onEventHandler;
};

// Final implementation. If there were more mixins, there could be for example,

class MyFooComponent : public AdapterImpl1<FooComponent>
{
};

// Main

int main() 
{
    MyFooComponent a;
    a.setOnEventHandler([](int val){
            printf("Handler val: %d\n", val);
        });

    // ...

    a.onEvent(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's ok. But you should use override in AdapterImpl1::setOnEventHandler

Comment: Override reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Comment: Thanks, I was just spitting out an example. This isn't my actual code, which uses override :)

Comment: (overrides added, because it started to bother me too)

Comment: I do believe that you wanted to use the `Base` type in `AdapterImpl1` somehow, my guess is that you wanted to inherit from it. Currently onEvent does not override and Component is not a base class of MyFooComponent